# Inserting string into the middle of a URL in R

Tags: r, rvest

I am using rvest to scrape an IMDB list and want to access the list of full cast and crew. Unfortunately, IMDB has created a summary page when you click on the title and it takes me to the wrong page.

This is the webpage I get: `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/?ref_=ttls_li_tt`

This is the webpage I need: `https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl`

Notice the addition of the `/fullcredits` in the URL.

How can I insert `/fullcredits` into the middle of a URL I have built?

```
#install.packages("rvest")
#install.packages("dplyr")

library(rvest) #webscraping package
library(dplyr) #piping 

link = "https://www.imdb.com/list/ls006266261/?st_dt=&mode=detail&page=1&sort=list_order,asc"
credits = "fullcredits/"
page = read_html(link)


name <- page %>% rvest::html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>% rvest::html_text()
movie_link = page %>% rvest::html_nodes(".lister-item-header a") %>%  html_attr("href") %>% paste("https://www.imdb.com", .,  sep="")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an option - get the `dirname` and `basename` from the link, replace the substring of the `basename` with new substring ("tt_ql_cl") and join them again with `file.path` after inserting the "fullcredits" in between

```
library(stringr)
movie_link2 <- file.path(dirname(movie_link), "fullcredits", 
       str_replace(basename(movie_link), "ttls_li_tt", "tt_ql_cl"))
```

-output

```
> head(movie_link2)
[1] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[2] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[3] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[4] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114814/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[5] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078788/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[6] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117951/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
> tail(movie_link2)
[1] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0144084/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[2] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119654/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[3] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0477348/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[4] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0080339/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[5] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0469494/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
[6] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt1375666/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way,

```
df1 = gsub("\\?.*", "", movie_link)
df = paste0(df1, 'fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl')
df
  [1] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0068646/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0099685/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
  [3] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0110912/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0114814/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
  [5] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0078788/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0117951/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
  [7] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0137523/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0108052/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
  [9] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118749/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0105236/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
 [11] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0111161/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0073195/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
 [13] "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0075314/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl" "https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0119488/fullcredits/?ref_=tt_ql_cl"
```